# Example code for ARM Cortex M3 based MCUs?

Tags: arm, stm32, cortex-m

More specifically the **STM32F107**.

I could barely find any code on ST's website, not even downloadable libraries (though I have found mention of some that indicates that they should exist?). This scares me a bit, as I don't want to choose a processor that is hard to use when there are other alternatives. (This particular processor meets all other requirements, though, so please do not interpret this as a question for alternatives)

So basically I was hoping that someone here could point me in the right direction.

I plan on using the Raisonance toolset, which is free, but seems to be limited to C. Both C and C++ (and even pure assembly) examples would be great, though. USB examples are of particular interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there is a lot of CM3 code that applies to more processors than just the STM32... but it seems that you asked about the STM32 specifically.

There is a [FreeRTOS port](http://www.stm32circle.com/projects/list.php) for the STM32 family.

The [STM32 Primer](http://www.stm32circle.com/hom/index.php) is a cheap hardware platform with lots of [user-supplied projects](http://www.stm32circle.com/projects/list.php) that can be downloaded.

Plus, ST has [some examples that can be downloaded](http://www.st.com/stonline/stappl/resourceSelector/app?page=resourceSelector&doctype=FIRMWARE&SubClassID=1169), and there is [a forum with lots of topics & examples](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/ARM%20CortexM3%20STM32/AllItems.aspx) as well.

You mentioned USB.  Look in the ST downloadable examples for the entry for USB on the go, UM0721.  The idiots did everything in HTML5 or flash or something (sorry, I"m an embedded guy, not a web developer) - I can't post a direct link...  if this description isn't good enough for you to find it, let me know, I'll try to be more explicit.

I have a bunch more stuff saved off & bookmarked, but I would think that would be enough to get you started?  Good luck & have fun.

**EDIT1:**  Olimex has a ton of great, [low-cost ARM boards](http://www.olimex.com/dev/arm_left.htm), including STM32-based boards.  The page for one of their boards has a [software download](http://www.olimex.com/dev/stm32-103stk.html) with lots of examples, including USB virtual COM port, USB audio, and USB mass storage.  I don't know what your hardware is and what toolset you're using, so of course you'll probably have to take the code & tailor it to your needs.  (*Disclaimer:* I have no association with Olimex whatsoever, I've just used a lot of their stuff & find them to be great bang-for-the-buck.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is this the OTG link you meant? http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/USER_MANUAL/CD00238039.pdf Do you know where this library can be downloaded?

Comment: Forget it, found it under resources